# Character Matching DNA Program

Tags: java, file-io, char

I am supposed to write a program using command line arguments to put in 3 different files, a human DNA sequence, a mouse DNA sequence, and an unknown sequence. Without using arrays, I have to compare each character and give the percent match as well aas which one it closely matches up to. Here is what I have so far

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.*;
public class Lucas_Tilak_Hw8_DNA 
{   
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        //First let's take in each file 
        File MouseFile = new File(args[0]);
        File HumanFile = new File(args[1]);
        File UnknownFile = new File(args[2]);

        //This allows us to view individual characters 
        FileInputStream m = new FileInputStream(MouseFile);
        FileInputStream h = new FileInputStream(HumanFile);
        FileInputStream u = new FileInputStream(UnknownFile);

        //This allows us to read each character one by one.
        DataInputStream mouse = new DataInputStream(m);
        DataInputStream human = new DataInputStream(h);
        DataInputStream unk = new DataInputStream(u);

        //We initialize our future numerators
        int humRight = 0;
        int mouRight = 0;

        //Now we set the counting variable
        int countChar = 0;
        for( countChar = 0; countChar < UnknownFile.length(); countChar++);
        {
            //initialize
            char unkChar = unk.readChar();
            char mouChar = mouse.readChar();
            char humChar = human.readChar();

            //add to numerator if they match
            if (unkChar == humChar)
            {
                humRight++;
            }
            if (unkChar == mouChar)
            {
                mouRight++;
            }
            //add to denominator
            countChar++;
        }   
        //convert to fraction
        long mouPercent = (mouRight/countChar);
        long humPercent = (humRight/countChar);

        //print fractions
        System.out.println("Mouse Compare: " + mouPercent);
        System.out.println("Human Compare: " + humPercent);
        if (mouPercent > humPercent)
        {
            System.out.println("mouse");
        }
        else if (mouPercent < humPercent)
        {
            System.out.println("human");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("identity cannot be determined");
        }
    }
}
```

If I put in random code {G, T, C, A} for each file I use, it doesn't seem to compare characters, so I get O = mouPercent and 0 = humPercent. Please Help!

Comment: Have you verified that `unk.readChar()`, `mouse.readChar()`, and `human.readChar()` are all returning a `char` object?

Comment: Well I guess it not, it is giving me weird 2x2 matrices like this

Comment: 䍁
䍁
䅔 I guess it isn't showing it now...

Comment: This isn't usually how DNA is compared, usually you're interested in something closer to longest shared substring. If you put random data in as human, unknown, and mouse, the degree of strict overlap with no shift is likely to be 0%. I'd hazard your program might be working just fine ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several errors in your code are to blame.

Remove the `;` from the end of your `for()` statement. Basically, you are only reading a single character from each file, and your comparison is strictly limited to that first set of characters. It's unlikely they will have any overlap.

Second error: don't use the "file length". Characters are typically encoded as more than one byte, so you're going to get inconsistent results this way. Better to query the stream to see if there are more bytes available, and stopping when you run out of bytes to read. Most Streams or Readers have an `available` or `ready` method that will let you determine if there is more to be read or not.

Third error: `DataInputStream` is not going to do what you expect it to do. [Read the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) -- you're getting strange characters because it's always pulling 2 bytes and building a character using a modified UTF-8 scheme, which only really maps to characters written by the corresponding `DataOutput` implementing classes. You should [research](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and modify your code to use `BufferedReader` instead, which will more naturally respect other character encodings like UTF-8, etc. which is most likely the encoding of the files you are reading in.

**TL;DR?** Your loop is broken, file length is a bad idea for loop terminating condition, and `DataInputStream` is a special unicorn, so use `BufferedReader` instead when dealing with characters in normal files.

Answer (score 0):

Try using floats instead of longs for your percentage variables.

Comment: Ok I did, but it is still showing me weird symbols when I print unkChar, mouChar and humChar right after I initialized them